# Can't catch DOM on $state.go

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
$state.go('client').then(uiService.showAdminPanel);
```

I am changing states in AngularJS with ui.router. `uiService.showAdminPanel` is a function, which looks for DOM elements in new state with `document.querySelector()`. 
However, it can not find anything inside `<ui-view>` neither on resolve nor `onSuccess()` function. 
I have tried to do this in `setTimeout()` in 10ms and it worked fine. Maybe someone knows, where does the delay come from?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event,toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams ){
 //TODO AFTER STATE CHANGE SUCCESSFULLY
})
```

Comment: is there a difference between your line and $transitions.onSuccess() function?

Comment: $transitions is a lifecycle hook in ui-routing 1.x series, refer this link https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#transition-lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Yea, the problem is that they say that I can make a hook onSuccess which is invoked after a transition successfully completes. I assume that after transition is complete, the DOM is available. But it is not for some short period of time